# Free shipping label/badge/text for conditional price in WooCommerce product/archive page under price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, badge

I want to add in the product page and archive, the text "free shipping" for products that have at least a certain price (say $ 49) free delivery, to later stylize it from css.
I did this, but it doesn't work.
Whoever gives me a helping hand, please, and if he has time, he can explain to me what I'm doing wrong, short.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'single_product_label', 10, 1 );
function single_product_label() {

    if ( is_product() || is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ):
        global $post, $product;
                
        if ( $price >= 49  ) {
    if ( empty( $product->get_shipping_class() ) ) {
        echo '<span class="freshipp">FREE SHIPPING</span>';
      endif;
    }
  }
```

Best regards.

Comment: Yes, I know about that, but it doesn't work for me. Although I changed the hooks. add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'single_product_label', 10, 1 );

Comment: I tried that code, and made several changes trying to make it work for the storefront, but I couldn't. My knowledge is limited in php and I do not know how to find the right solution. Can anyone please help me? Can anyone adapt the code for standard hooks?
Thanks.

Comment: This code partially works. But it looks for all prices / products.

Comment: add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_summary_text', 15 );
function custom_single_product_summary_text() {
    global $product;
    
    $price_threshold = 49;
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        $price = $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true );
    } else {
        $price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product );
    }
    if ( $price < $price_threshold ) {
        $message = __("FREE SHIPPING", "text_domain");
    } 
echo '<p class="freeshipp">' . $message . '</p>';
}